# Is there a reason why this post just got deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

Any reason why [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523255/what-is-a-great-free-icon-editor-for-windows) just got deleted by a moderator (after being around for more than 5 years).

(It was very helpful to me, even if considered off-topic)

Here is a screenshot for <10k users:

[image]

Comment: Because of section 4 as [stated here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Can you grab a screen for <10k users?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do understand. But after 5 years?

Comment: It would mislead new users, that such questions could be asked and on topic, I guess.

Comment: Somebody with 15k rep should have a basic understanding of what this site is about…

Comment: The visible comments in that screenshot are hilarious in their apoplexy. "Rediculous" indeed.

Comment: Betcha mods got sick of handling flags on that mess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it had gotten deleted as off topic, because it's not even remotely related to programming. A better place for such a question would be to post in a graphic designers forum or something. I do not think that stack exchange has a forum for such a thing however.

Comment: There is a [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), but I don't see that as within their scope (it doesn't say no recommendations, but I don't see them in open questions either).  More appropriately, it might have been on topic for [SoftwareRecommendations.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), however the lack of information wouldn't meet there [enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) criteria for a good (dev forced) migration there.

Answer (score 23):

It's deleted because it's so **blatantly off-topic** that it's not worth keeping around on our site in any form. Not even *remotely* related to programming.

Comment: @UweKeim First, we can only migrate questions which are younger than 60 days. Second, that question wouldn't be on-topic at that site either.

Comment: @UweKeim software recommendations would reject that question without a through...

Comment: animuson (and a ping to @UweKeim) SE *has* done [old migrations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/3716/revisions) to software recs in the past for high quality closed questions on other sites that would be a good fit on SoftwareRec, though you are very correct that this post wouldn't meet there standards of [enough](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).